# Cloudformation: CommaDelimitedList of Cert ARNs for ListenerCertificate Resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to pass in a CommaDelimitedList to populate a List of Certs in a `AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::ListenerCertificate` resource.

**Error:** Value of property Certificates must be a list of objects

I tried a few formats, including the following:

```
Parameters:
  pAdditionalAlbListenerCertArns:
    Type: CommaDelimitedList
    Default: "arn:someCert1, arnsomeCert2"
    Description: enter list of the ACM Certificates (Arns)

## Resource Format 1 - I would think this way would work as the result is [thing1, thing2]
Resources:
rCertificatesList:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::ListenerCertificate
    Properties:
      Certificates: ! Ref  pAdditionalAlbListenerCertArns

## Resource Format 2 - I know this should not work, because it's a single item trying to be populated by a list.
Resources:
rCertificatesList:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::ListenerCertificate
    Properties:
      Certificates: 
        CertificateArn: ! Ref  pAdditionalAlbListenerCertArns
```

Apparently Cfn is not smart enough to prepend each item with `CertificateArn:`.

I have also tried combinations of `!Split`, `!Sub`, and `!Join` which gave the same error. Currently I am having to key in the certs directly, which is not viable. While I could create individual parameters for each cert, or use a `!Select` to grab them out of the list, I don't know how many I will have in each environment (DEV/TEST/PROD).

I know this works cleanly for things like security groups; am I missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format of [AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::ListenerCertificate Certificate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-elasticloadbalancingv2-listener-certificates.html) is:

```
  Certificates: 
    - CertificateArn: String
```

Non of your uses will work with that. In fact, nothing will work, as this would require looping, which is **not supported** by CloudFormation. The only feasibale way to achieve what you want is by developing your own [custom CFN macro](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html).

Alliteratively, if you will be requiring a lot of iteration in your CFN code, maybe CFN is not the right tool for you. Have a look at CDK or terraform which have rich support for loops.

Comment: I was afraid of this. 

For now I am going to do a string of CertificateArn values with an AWS:NoValue for ones that may or may not exist.

I agree that Tf is superior in virtually every way here, but the environment I'm working in is 100% Cfn for the past 3 years and adding a new IaC tool is a larger conversation.